# Code snippet floating in mid-air as a tooltip, cannot hide it, after extracting method [IntelliJ Idea / Android Studio]

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Trying to perform the Ctrl + G (Go to line) keyboard shortcut, seems I accidentally activated a feature that pins the code the cursor was previously on.

After closing and reopening the file, things are worse; the code snippets still are floating over the screen, no matter if I move the Android Studio window.

I have searched keyboard shortcuts using [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html), but no luck.

Is there a way to disable or revert this?
[image]

Noticed by comment below and confirmed by myself: This happens **after extracting a method**.

Comment: `Invalidating caches and restart` (as suggested below) didn't fix it. Every time I `extract a method` via the keyboard shortcut that floating thing comes up and won't ever go away until I restart the IDE. 
Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: No, I did not. But I noted it happens when I extract a method. Your comment was useful.

Comment: In occasions, I have been able to get rid of those permanent tooltips by invalidating caches and restart, but this should not be the way to disable them, as I still don't know which is the keyboard shortcut to toggle this "pin snippet" function.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get rid of those permanent tooltips by invalidating caches and restart, but this should *not* be the way to disable them, as I still don't know which is the keyboard shortcut to toggle this "pin snippet" function.